# How to drive two stepper motors simultaneously

Tags: python

I am using a raspberry pi model B to drive one stepper motor with the L293D chip and python.
Now I would like to control two stepper motors simultaneously with two different L293D chips and python.
I have read that this can be done with python threading but it is very difficult.
Is there another way to accomplish that with python?
Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it still "just" a matter of turning on and off some GPIO pins - only twice the number you're currently toggling? I'm not exactly sure what you want or what the problem is but I wonder if you need threading at all. Seeing some code or the expected output would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jDo said you can just deal with the situation as another set of GPIO pins.

Here is my blog post where I did just that http://jumpstation.co.uk/flog/Mar2014.html#190320142109

The code simple copies the previous stepper motor code and changes the GPIO pins assignments. You pass in the number of steps you want each motor to do on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is you use a [L298N Motor Controller](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CAG6GX2). You have to have a separate power source for it but you can power and control 2 motors at once using the GPIO pins and python

Answer (score 0):

I encountered issues when adding a second motor. The GIL does not allow for both threads to run simultaneously.
Mi solution was to add a centralized stepping class (Navigation) and have it ran by a dedicated python process (so your app does not compete). The readme shows how to initiate the motors.
I ise a motor Hat with two DRV8825 onboard.
https://github.com/juanmf/StepperMotors

Demo video: https://youtu.be/WprF3Dy7BbE

This video shows how to set it up.
https://youtu.be/8nMbXOeY1qs?si=xTRq5W1MaIGWg8PT